# How to get OpenVPN Windows client bypass its own traffic correctly?

Tags: windows, networking, routing, openvpn

Typically we bypass OpenVPN traffic (making its own encapsulated packets go outside the tunnel) by adding a static route towards VPN server via the default gateway, and it's the behavior of `--redirect-gateway`. But the thing is, this leaks traffic when client accesses other services of the same server, e.g. HTTPS, FTP, NTP, etc.

In Linux, we have `--mark` to mark encapsulated packets and bypass them using route rules. Android's VPN system can also bypass encapsulated packets correctly. What about Windows? How to achieve the same behavior in Windows?